# Remove advanced search link from top.search in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

In Magento/Blank an advanced search link appears under the search form by default. I have unsuccessfully been attempting to remove this by referencing the block name for removal. My issue is, not being able to determine what the actual block is called. Turning on path hints and block names was not helpful, nor was looking in the module folder. What am I missing?

```
<referenceBlock name="advanced.search" remove="true"/>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

it's the solution:

```
<referenceBlock name="advanced-search-link" remove="true"/>
```

every static links search it inside default.xml of any module our case is in :
**vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/view/frontend/layout/default.xml**

Comment: The link still shows in my store. I added the default.xml inside `mytheme/Magento_Catalog-search/layout/` . Is that the right folder to put this file into?

Comment: I used it inside my theme at `mytheme/Magento_Search/layout/default.xml`. My code is the following
```<referenceContainer name="header.row">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="Magento_Search::form.mini.phtml" after="store.menu" />
            <referenceBlock name="advanced-search-link" remove="true"/>
        </referenceContainer>```

Comment: that is not the correct path. You should not modify anything in vendor/magento

Answer (score 2):

The correct path to folder is

**app/design/frontend/ThemeDirectory/YourTheme/default.xml**

Open `default.xml` & Put this code anywhere after

```
<body>
<referenceBlock name="advanced-search-link" remove="true"/>
```

It will remove the advanced - search link from ALL THE PAGES.

Comment: Magento 2.3 This worked for me    <referenceBlock name="catalog-search-advanced-link" remove="true"/>