# Remove Advanced Search Link From Header Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, catalogsearch, magento-2.1, layout-update

I am trying to remove the advanced search link from the header in Magento 2 but it doesn't seem to be disappearing after I've extended the default.xml layout file found in the catalog search module. My default.xml file is located in the following directory:

(theme_dir)/Magento_CatalogSearch/layout/default.xml

And contains the following contents:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="advanced-search-link" remove="true"/>
</body>
</page>
```

Is this the correct way to extend the catalog search default layout file? In order to remove a block from layout do you have to override the layout file rather than extend it?

Comment: Might be helpful http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94317/remove-advanced-search-link-from-top-search-in-magento-2

Comment: If you have cache enabled, be sure to clear it.

Comment: All caches are disabled with the mode set to developer. After manually clearing all the caches it still doesn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following link helped me resolve the issue:

[Remove advanced search link from top.search in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94317/remove-advanced-search-link-from-top-search-in-magento-2)

Answer (score 0):

Use this inside 
(theme_dir)/Magento_Search/layout/default.xml OR
(theme_dir)/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="advanced-search-link" remove="true"/>
```